# How to create a custom magic file database

Tags: file, unix

The unix `file` command uses a "magic" file database to determine which type of data a file contains, independently of the file's name or extension.

I need to craft my custom magic database for testing purposes, but I fail to find how to create one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can `man magic` for a description for how to create your own magic file. Then use `file -C -m <your magic file>` to compile it, and `file -m <your magic file>` to use it.

Comment: if you have root privilege, you can edit magic or magic.mime as need be rather than create a new file

Comment: again how does this help? If it is in the manual can you give an example?

Comment: @PauloNeves the details of the syntax isn't trivial, as the man page (or a [link to it](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) ) is much better. "Each line of the file specifies a test to be performed.  A test compares the data starting at a particular offset in the file with a byte value, a string or a numeric value.  If the test succeeds, a message is printed.  The line consists of the following fields: offset, type, test, message". cweiske has an example as an answer below.

Comment: For rather simple as well as more complex examples you can browse the included [magic files](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir).

Answer (score 4):

In this article: https://linux.die.net/man/1/file (or `man file`)

search for `magic.mgc` for explanation

> The information identifying   these   files   is   read   from      the   compiled   magic  file /usr/share/file/magic.mgc, or  `/usr/share/file/magic`  if  the  compile file  does  not exist. In addition file will look in $HOME/.magic.mgc, or `$HOME/.magic` for magic entries.

Comment: How does this help the poster create a custom magic database?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following magic file now for my unit tests:

```
0       search/1/c      =<?php                  PHP script text
!:mime  text/x-unittest
```

With it, every php file (beginning with `<?php`) will get the MIME type `text/x-unittest`.

---

Also see http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/custom-magic-db.htm

Comment: What does the `/1/c` mean after `search`? and does the spacing matter?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic  Like the string directive, searches with regex at the first position case insensitive.