# Is it possible to enable CORS in the PHP CLI server?

Tags: php, cors

Is it possible to enable CORS in the [PHP CLI server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) (and if so, how)?

Edit: To address comments such as I should just include the header in my scripts, note that I do not have any PHP files/scripts in my code. I am simply using the PHP CLI server as a lightweight local hosting option. Thus ideally the answer will provide a CLI option, or show that there is none.

Comment: The same way as any other server because you issue the CORS headers in your script.

Comment: If you don't serve PHP scripts with that server, then you have no options in manipulating which headers are sent. To enable CORS, you must send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If you can't use PHP, you can't send the header. If you can use PHP, you can send the header. That's about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start the server with DocumentRoot in webhook folder with php routings script :

```sh
php -S localhost:8888 -t webhook webhook/dev-routings.php
```

webhook/dev-routings.php :

```php
<?php
// Copyright Monwoo 2017, service@monwoo.com
// Enabling CORS in bultin dev to test locally with multiples servers
// used to replace lack of .htaccess support inside php builting webserver.
// call with :
// php -S localhost:8888 -t webhook webhook/dev-routings.php
$CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOWED = "http://localhost:3000";  // or '*' for all   

function consoleLog($level, $msg) {
    file_put_contents("php://stdout", "[" . $level . "] " . $msg . "\n");
}

function applyCorsHeaders($origin) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $origin");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept');
}

if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|csv)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    consoleLog('info', "Transparent routing for : " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    return false;
} else if (preg_match('/^.*$/i', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    $filePath = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}";
    applyCorsHeaders($CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOWED);

    if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
        consoleLog('info', "File not found Error for : " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        // return false;
        http_response_code(404);
        echo "File not Found : {$filePath}";
        return true;
    }
    $mime = mime_content_type($filePath);
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179337/mime-content-type-returning-text-plain-for-css-and-js-files-only
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236191/how-to-create-a-custom-magic-file-database
    // Otherwise, you can use custom rules :
    $customMappings = [
        'js' => 'text/javascript', //'application/javascript',
        'css' => 'text/css',
    ];
    $ext = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // consoleLog('Debug', $ext);
    if (array_key_exists($ext, $customMappings)) {
        $mime = $customMappings[$ext];
    }
    consoleLog('info', "CORS added to file {$mime} : {$filePath}");
    header("Content-type: {$mime}");
    echo file_get_contents($filePath);
    return true;
} else {
    consoleLog('info', "Not catched by routing, Transparent serving for : "
    . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    return false; // Let php bultin server serve
}
```

Comment: It is causing error Directory webhook does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you that are still scratching your head about this, I had this same problem and figured it out. For me, proxying from the Webpack Dev Server to my PHP dev server didn't work.

It seems that the PHP built in server has problems with CORS when you use localhost for the server. Instead, you should use either your local IP address, or just 127.0.0.1, which again points to your local computer. So, you would start your server like this:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8888 -t public
```

Now the Webpack Dev Server proxy works. You can use 0.0.0.0 too. Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot confirm problems with `localhost` and CORS.

Comment: Upvoted because for me this was the solution. Couldn't get our Cypress e2e tests running on my local machine when php was serving from `localhost`, but with `127.0.0.1` it works

Answer (score 0):

#### People coming from google and using the built-in-php-server: put on the first line in your `file-to-be-served.php`:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Taken from:
https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this problem for staic files was to create a router.php file with the content bellow and start the server like this `sudo php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t public router.php`

```
<?php

$path = pathinfo($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
if ($path["extension"] == "yaml") {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    readfile($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
    return true;
}

return false;

?>
```

`public` is the folder from where my app is served (a Laravel application in my case).

You can update the `router.php` script to include more file extensions (js, css) that should have CORS enabled.

For the application itself (no static files), you should find a way to add the following header to all requests.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar issue and needed to serve using php cli server and let my app show the images from that server.
A quick solution is to implement a small php wrapper for image access.
eg: make a php file

> showimage.php

with following content

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo file_get_contents($_GET['image']+".jpg");
?>
```

in the same folder as your public 'images' folder, then access the image (with .jpg extension) as follows

> http://localhost/path-to-images-folder/showimage.php?image=imagename1

that way any image in that folder can b accessed with appropriate header added.

Note that such a solution should be secured against access to all files so use the appropriate extension as per your need

Answer (score -1):

This feature is not implemented in the internal web server. The web server is just meant for basic testing and not for production. Please note the *red* box on top of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

> **Warning**
>
> This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

Comment: You told: `I am simply using the PHP CLI server as a lightweight local hosting option.`. I think the manual says all

Comment: I didn't down vote it. Someone else did. If there is nothing about it in docs as you claim I will accept a modified answer that says that, though only after waiting a little bit to see if anyone knows of undocumented support

Comment: Also, to be more clear, your answer as it stands now does not show that the feature is not implemented - it possibly just shows that it isn't documented.

Comment: I edited that. I still wonder why you expect such a feature, after reading the *red* box on top of the documentation. Also usually a manual does mention what is implemented but not what is not implemented.

Comment: Basic testing should include CORS, to basicly test CORS.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8400/resources/Auth.postman_collection.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy.  So yeah... downvoting the answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarification on this old post! @MatthewHerbst Do you mind un-accepting my answer? I cannot delete the accepted answer