# mime_content_type returning text/plain for css and js files only

Tags: php, apache, mime

I'm encountering this weird issue with PHP's mime_content_type, it works fine, except for CSS and JavaScript files, which it returns text/plain for (PHP's default mime is set to do text/html).

Modifying the mime.types file seems to make no difference (its path on httpd.conf is correct).

Examples

```
<?php
  echo(mime_content_type('index.html')); // returns text/html
  echo(mime_content_type('default.png')); // returns image/png
  echo(mime_content_type('bootstrap.min.js')); // returns text/plain
  echo(mime_content_type('css/animate.css')); // returns text/plain
  echo(mime_content_type('css/style.css')); // returns text/x-asm
?>
```

The same exact files served on the same exact Apache installation gets correctly marked on their `Content-Type` headers, it's almost as if PHP's using its mime detection mechanism.

I'm using `Wamp 3.0.6 64-bit` and the built-in `PHP 7.0.10` on `Windows 10 64-bit build 15063.483 mod_mime and mode_mime_magic`
 are enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PHP doc is pretty explicit about that:

> Returns the MIME content type for a file as determined by using
>   information from the magic.mime file.

PHP and Apache don't use the same mime databases. Apache uses `mime.types` but PHP uses `magic.mime` (can't remember where it's located, `/etc/` on a Unix system, I think)

No sure how to edit it on Windows but here are some tips for Linux: [How to create a custom magic file database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236191/how-to-create-a-custom-magic-file-database)

Comment: You, sir, are spot on, it looks like I'm left to do exactly what Apache does, guess the correct mime by the file extension.