# Display png image from folder

Tags: php, png

A row in my database contains the name of the image of the product among other information about a product and all of images get saved in the same folder. I want to retrieve those images and display them in HTML, since I am using the apache server, I cannot just give the link of the file. I am currently using the following code:

```
$imgg = "/var/abc/def/product/";
.
.
<img src="data:<?php echo mime_content_type($imgg . $row[2])?>;charset=utf-
8;base64,<?php $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imgg . $row[2])); 
echo $image; ?>" alt="" border=3 height=50 width=50/>
```

Obviously, the image name is in the third column of the database. It will be something like 'jkl.png'. This code works perfectly if the image is JPG. I have read online that there is a bug with mime_content_type when it comes to png, but I haven't been able to find another solution. So please help me solve this.

Comment: "since I am using the apache server, I cannot just give the link of the file". This is not necessarily true. Why can't you? Apache can serve PNG files, as long as they're within the website root / virtual directory. There's not really any reason for the base64 encoding here. You could check your specific apache config to make sure there's a mime type entry for PNG. P.S. If you link to where you found this bug report, perhaps we can check if it's actually related or not.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, the images aren't going to in the website root directory. Another program is running in the machine that deals with the database and hence all the pulled information isn't in the root directory.

Comment: can't the process be changed to write the files into a location that's serveable by apache? Or make that existing location into a virtual directory? That would be simpler, assuming it's not some sort of security issue.

Comment: It probably can, but I'd like to know how to do it this way too. If you google, there are many forums where developers have complained that it doesn't work with png, it returns the file type as plain text.

Comment: can you provide a link to any of these reports? And what version of PHP and Apache are you running? This could also be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179337/mime-content-type-returning-text-plain-for-css-and-js-files-only Have you checked the contents of your magic.mime file?

Comment: https://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/157971-mime_content_type-png-image-returns-text-plain
https://www.virtualmin.com/node/9878
apache2 php7

Comment: Those links are dated 2005 and 2009 respectively. I wouldn't just assume that the problem still applies to newer versions. Anyway like I said, check your magic.mime file first to see if there's a suitable entry for PNG. That's as per that link I gave above, and also the documentation for the mime_content_type method: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: That's a fair point, there were plenty more, but I'll get back to you on this after doing a bit more research. But yes, I am using the function, and its working perfectly with jpeg but not with png and hence I can conclude that it isn't working.

Comment: Check the magic.mime file first and if that's not the problem then we can look into it further