# How do you create a magic file in linux?

Tags: linux, file

i tried reading up on how to create magic files but i could not find any in linux. please help

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/7236262/4826457 what you mean? How is it related to git?

Comment: `touch magic` :-)